# Excel categorize list transfer

Tags: excel, list, excel-formula, categories, vlookup

I'm trying to create a summarize information for all of the supplier our company have. I have my sheet1 as my main database where in all our suppliers are listed. I would like to create several additional sheets which will contain each specific nature of business of the suppliers.

What I would like to happen is, given that my sheet2 is for the suppliers who specialize in "PRINTING", sheet3 is for those who specialize in "I.T EQUIPMENT". Whenever I add a supplier on my sheet1, it will automatically be added on my sheet2 or 3 as well if it matches its specialty. Please help!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you expect in the answer? Do you want a formula or vba? Please provide more details about the conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your `Sheet1` is Master Sheet where names of all Suppliers and their Specialties are listed in Column A and Column B respectively.

If in `Sheet2` you want to list down the all ***Suppliers with Printing*** as specialty, write following formula in `Cell A2` of `Sheet2`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A$2:A$25,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!B$2:B$25="Printing",ROW(A$2:A$25)-ROW(A$2)+1),ROWS(A$2:A2))),"")
```

and drag/copy it down as required. This is an array formula so enter this formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Likewise, if in `Sheet3` you want to list down all ***Suppliers with IT Equipment*** as specialty, write following formula in `Cell A2` of `Sheet3`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A$2:A$25,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!B$2:B$25="IT Equipment",ROW(A$2:A$25)-ROW(A$2)+1),ROWS(A$2:A2))),"")
```

and drag/copy it down as required. Again, this is an array formula so enter this formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**To automatically update the list in `Sheet2` and `Sheet3`**, you'll have to take care of two things:

**1.** Range in the above formula is row 2 to row 25, you'll have to enter the range till the row you think your list could be extended. For example if your list will not get past the row 1000 then formula for Printing in `Sheet2` becomes

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A$2:A$1000,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!B$2:B$100="Printing",ROW(A$2:A$1000)-ROW(A$2)+1),ROWS(A$2:A2))),"")
```

**2.** You'll have to drag/copy down this formula in `Sheet2` and `Sheet3` till the row you think the list could extend based on the `Sheet1` data.

---

You can even use just one formula for all the sheets as follows:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A$2:A$25,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!B$2:B$25=$C$1,ROW(A$2:A$25)-ROW(A$2)+1),ROWS(A$2:A2))),"")
```

where `Cell C1` of each sheet will have the specialty name.

See image for reference

[image]

Comment: thank you for your help. however, it did not work on my end. Here's several details from my worksheet. My Sheet1 is named "DATABASE", Sheet2 is "I.T EQUIPMENT". My table row starts at A8 in "DATABASE" sheet, and the same on my "I.T EQUIPMENT" sheet. Here's the code I used after editing yours, =IFERROR(INDEX(DATABASE!A$8:A$25,SMALL(IF(DATABASE!F$8:F$25="IT EQUIPMENT",ROW(A$8:A$25)ROW(A$8)+1),ROWS(A$8:A25))),"")        My table columns are "SUPPLIER NAME [A] / SUPPLIER ADDRESS [B] / CONTACT # [C] / CONTACT PERSON / [D] / WEBSITE [E] / SPECIALTY [F]. Did I miss something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @KelvinJhon - Your formula should be `=IFERROR(INDEX(DATABASE!A$8:A$25,SMALL(IF(DATABASE!F$8:F$25="IT EQUIPMENT",ROW(A$8:A$25)-ROW(A$8)+1),ROWS(A$8:A8))),"")`

Comment: The result it showing is: it copies what is inside the A8 (which in this case, "Sample 1" with the SPECIALTY of "Printing Services". The column where the SPECIALTY is "IT EQUIPMENT" are columns A9 and A10. Also, when I drag down/copy the formula, it does not display anything else. I would've included images here, however, I don't know how to :(

Comment: @KelvinJhon - You can upload image on any of the online file sharing site and share the link here. If you can share your file I can look into it.

Comment: [Sheet 1](https://postimg.org/image/phvso8bi9/)                                             [Sheet 2](https://postimg.org/image/6e72lmo1t/)    Hope these helps. Thank you!

Comment: @KelvinJhon - I am so sorry. I forgot to mention that the formula in the answer is an array formula. So instead of pressing enter, press Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Comment: [Sheet 1](https://postimg.org/image/p59phrbfr/)                                           [Sheet 2](https://postimg.org/image/bpra61sbr/) these are the actual sheets. sadly it did not work :/ any suggestions? Thank you for your time btw. Really appreciate all the help!

Comment: @KelvinJhon - In `Sheet2` your formula has `ROW(A$8:A$25)`, change it to `ROW(A$8:A$46)`

Comment: your patience and knowledge have helped me big time! Thanks bro. Be well!